# Process stalling in simple for-loop, dependent on iterator type (potential JVM bug?)

Tags: java, for-loop, jvm

A very simple for-loop that I used as a dummy to keep my machine busy blocked all processes of my JVM. The stalling persisted even in the most simple constellation.

Here is an example of two for-loops (the first blocking, the second not), the only difference being the type of the iterator 'i', namely int vs. long:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new MyTimerHandler(), new Date(), 1000);
    float b = 1;

    // after a few seconds this loop uses 200% CPU and blocks the timer 
    for (int i=0; i<2000000000; i++) {
        b += i/3.141592;
    }
    System.out.println("Result: " + b);
    b = 1;

    // this version uses 100% CPU throughout the entire loop and doesn't block the timer
    for (long i=0; i<2000000000L; i++) {
        b += i/3.141592;
    }
    System.out.println("Result: " + b);
    timer.cancel();
 }
}
// helps to show whether the JVM is stalled or not
class MyTimerHandler extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("timestamp=" + new Date().toString());
    }
}
```

We have reproduced the problem on two different machines/jvms:

- Arch Linux 3.7.7-1-ARCH ... x86_64 GNU/Linux
  java version "1.7.0_09", Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
- OSX 10.8.2 ... x86_64
  java version "1.7.0_07", Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)

---

UPDATE & Clarification:

- The question is, WHY and WHAT EXACTLY is happening, not to "solve" the given example, i.e why does the first for-loop behave so weirdly, using 2x more CPU and blocking all threads of the JVM.
- The example code terminates and gives the correct result.
- The timer is just for demonstration, the problems occurs with or without it.
- The limit of int is way above 2,000,000,000.
- The problem affects all tested JVMs so far.
- JProfiler and other debugging tools are interrupted/stalled during the first for-loop as well.

Comment: Try setting the timer to be a Daemon. 
Timer timer = new Timer(true);

And read the documentation, this is not a bug it is expected behavior when another thread is blocking.

Comment: @gbtimmon the issue persists even with:
Timer timer = new Timer(true);
this does not solve the issue. Also I'd like to understand whats going wrong!

Comment: Also try changing schedule to scheduleAtFixedRate

Comment: just for clarification: the int max value is 2^31-1 = 2147483647 which is larger than "2000000000" i.e. that can not be the problem either

Comment: it is not the scheduler... we tried the code without the timer in JProfiler and the whole thing stalled on us as well -- the timer is just there for convenience, to show the problem!

Comment: It works fine on OSX 10.8.2 Java 1.7.0_11. Strange that it uses 200% cpu (other than for a short period). Have you tried getting stack traces (jstack PID) to see that the JVM actually executes what you expect. Perhaps Adding a debug print every million iterations or so in the loop to see if there is any progress?

Comment: Interesting puzzle. Just one additional piece: Adding a debug print like 'if (i%200000000==0) { System.err.println("at "+i+" it is "+b); }' inside the first loop make the timer stall around the time the debug statement prints the `at 200000000 it is ...` but comes back at `at 400000000 ...`. If using `i==200000000` instead of `i%200000000==0` the timer stops creating output around the time the debug output appears and only prints a last result just before the result is printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the the optimizing compiler (probably trying to unroll the loop). It runs on a separate thread and that is why you see 200% CPU utilization.
If you create a method out of the first loop and run it twice the second time it works as expected.

Try running your JVM like this:

```
java -Xint Main
```

That options disables the HotSpot compiler. In my case the timer thread prints on every second with no pauses.

If you run with `java -XX:+PrintCompilation Main` you will see that the compiler prints "made not entrant" in the middle of the first loop.

```
    79    6             java.lang.String::lastIndexOf (52 bytes)
    90    1 %           test.Main::main @ 33 (141 bytes)
    timestamp=Thu Feb 14 12:10:40 PST 2013
    timestamp=Thu Feb 14 12:10:41 PST 2013
    timestamp=Thu Feb 14 12:10:42 PST 2013
    timestamp=Thu Feb 14 12:10:43 PST 2013
    timestamp=Thu Feb 14 12:10:44 PST 2013
    13202    1 %           test.Main::main @ -2 (141 bytes)   made not entrant
    timestamp=Thu Feb 14 12:10:53 PST 2013
    Result: 1.80143985E16
    13202    2 %           test.Main::main @ 85 (141 bytes)
    timestamp=Thu Feb 14 12:10:54 PST 2013
    timestamp=Thu Feb 14 12:10:55 PST 2013
```

Swap the loops and it prints "made not entrant" between the two loops.

```
    72    6             java.lang.String::lastIndexOf (52 bytes)
    85    1 %           test.Main::main @ 33 (141 bytes)
    timestamp=Thu Feb 14 12:12:38 PST 2013
    timestamp=Thu Feb 14 12:12:39 PST 2013
    timestamp=Thu Feb 14 12:12:40 PST 2013
    timestamp=Thu Feb 14 12:12:41 PST 2013
    15415    1 %           test.Main::main @ -2 (141 bytes)   made not entrant
    Result: 1.80143985E16
    15415    2 %           test.Main::main @ 88 (141 bytes)
    timestamp=Thu Feb 14 12:12:42 PST 2013
    timestamp=Thu Feb 14 12:12:43 PST 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AProVE (http://aprove.informatik.rwth-aachen.de) I proved that the first loop indeed is terminating. Please have a closer look at the other possibly non-terminating code, most likely the timer (as indicated in the comments).

Comment: Maybe I wasn't exactly clear with what I meant by "stalling" -- the code runs through, that has never been of any concern, however the JVM  i.e. all other threads are blocked and the CPU usage is unexpectedly high -- it behaves very weirdly for no apparent reason!